# Find the rank of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & -1 & 1\\ 3 & 0 & 4 & 2\\ 6 & 9 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

Tags: matrices, proof-explanation, determinant, matrix-rank

Find the rank of the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & -1 & 1\\
3 & 0 &  4 & 2\\
6 & 9 & -3 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$.

Now, I know that the rank of a matrix is actually equal to the greatest positive integer $r$ such that the matrix has atleast a non-zero minor of order $r$. However, I want to know that how to calculate the minor of an element of a non-square, i.e., a 'purely' rectangular matrix. I know how to calculate the minors of a square matrix of each "elements" , but I don't get how to calculate minors of order $k$, in general, from a given rectangular matrix? Like in the above example how to calculate minors of order $3$?

Comment: You can use the Gauss-Jordan method of elimination.

Comment: @Sebastiano Actually, the rank is $2$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you very much. I have used a tool on line in wrong manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant of any of the four $3\times3$ submatrices of $A$ is $0$, and therefore the rank is at most $2$. But $\left|\begin{smallmatrix}2&3\\3&0\end{smallmatrix}\right|=-9\ne0$, and so $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$.

Comment: But can you list out how to calculate minors of order $3$?...I dont quite get this ...I only know how to calculate minors of each element in a square matrix ....but dont know how to calculate minors of any arbitary order from a given rectangular matrix...

Comment: The minors of order $3$ of $A$ are$$\begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 & -1 \\ 3 & 0 & 4 \\ 6 & 9 & -3\end{bmatrix},\ \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3 & 1 \\ 3 & 0 & 2 \\ 6 & 9 & 3\end{bmatrix},\  \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 & 1 \\ 3 & 4 & 2 \\ 6 & -3 & 3\end{bmatrix}\text{, and }\begin{bmatrix}3 & -1 & 1 \\ 0 & 4 & 2 \\ 9 & -3 & 3\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Thanks you so very much ! So we cant actually consider $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1& 1\\ 3 &  0 & 4\\ 9 & -3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$, and all other possible $3×3$ determinant as minors , right ? The minors should maintain the symmetry(or pattern ) as shown by you in your previous comment , correct?

Comment: The minors are whatever (square) matrices remain after removing some lines and/or columns from the original matrix. The ones that I got are those obtained by removing from $A$ one of its columns.

Comment: Thanks for responding! So given, a matrix the general procedure is to delete a row(or rows) or a column(or columns)  and check if there is any square matrices or not which is then to be considered as a minor of a particular order ....

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much ! I do get it now...